# Path Fill property binding erratic behavior?

Tags: wpf, xaml, path, fill

I got some kind of weird behavior while trying to use all the power of MVC... :)
I was to trying to bound a simple Path Fill property to some value and cannot succeed.

As a small exemple is worth...
Here's how to reproduce simply:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Path Name="p" Data="M 0,0 h 30 v 30 h -30 v -30" Fill="Beige">
        <Path.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ch}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Path.Style>
    </Path>

    <CheckBox Name="ch" Margin="35,12,-35,-12" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

An other issue, It works with this layout but not with a similar one (removing Fill from declaration):

```
<Path Name="p" Data="M 0,0 h 30 v 30 h -30 v -30">
    <Path.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ch}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ch}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="Blue"/>
                    </DataTrigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Path.Style>
    </Path>
```

Could someone enlighten me on the cause ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not set any `Fill` on the path itself if you want to change it in a style as that will override your style due to [dependency property value precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Move the initial `Fill` value into a `Setter` of the style.

Comment: Indeed, and the counter example I had built up did'nt work because of an typo..
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Got a follow up on this one.. :)